# latex source file got corrupted after converting to word document using GrindEq

Tags: errors

My latex source file become like this after converting to word document using GrindEq. Can anyone guide me to get my original tex file back?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Check if you are opening the file with the proper encoding (usually utf8).

Comment: That looks like it is the docx file that is the intended output. If you have over-written the input with the output, you would be best to restore the original from backup.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik not this time:-)  first two bytes = PK and contains document.xml.rels means the file is a zip file in docx format

Comment: And of course, you have tried to edit that file with Word or LibreOffice to check if the code is still readable when opened properly,  not only with a plain text/LaTeX editor ...right?